# jquery ajax always get error section when try to pass json object(simple)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

```
 var jso = { "namep": "a", "age": "10" };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', 
                url: '@Url.Action("gettestjsn","Cart")',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify(jso),

                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.namep);

                },
                error: function () { alert("err"); }
            });
```

this code always go to error function and i does not fire my mvc action,aslo i have a prop class which does match to this json  obj. why is that i m new to json and jquery ajax please help
this is my action

```
 public ActionResult gettestjsn(jso  jso) 
        {


//do some here

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: check your browser console is there any error... what is the response status

Comment: You don't need to call `JSON.stringify`.  Just pass `jso` itself as the `data` value.

Comment: change the error handler to `error: function (jqxhr, status, error) { alert("err:" + status + ':' + error); }`

Comment: some times it fires success section and error function

Comment: why that execute both functions

Comment: "error Internal Server Error"  hi arun i m getting this error how do i fix it

Comment: @user2582841 did any of the answers work?

Answer (score 0):

Remove contentType from the ajax attributes and add

```
     dataType: 'json',
```

This will work if the url is correct

Answer (score 0):

this is how your code should look like

```
var jso = { "namep": "a", "age": "10" };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', 
                url: '@Url.Action("gettestjsn","Cart")',
                data: jso,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.namep);
                },
                error: function () { alert("err"); }
            });
```

Also i would refrain from using alerts. Either use console.log or debug using the inspector in your browser (comes inbuilt with chrome) to see what your data from the server looks like.

Comment: i updated error part like arun said nw it showing error blow <br/>"error Internal Server Error"

Comment: if your are getting some internal server error then there is something wrong with your code on the server side. can't help too much there unless you post that too..

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

var jso = { "namep": "a", "age": "10" };

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', 
                url: '/Cart/gettestjsn',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: jso,

                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.namep);

                },
                error: function (jqxhr, status, error) { alert("err:" + status + ':' + error); }
            });
```

and your action should be,

```
[HttpPost]
     public ActionResult gettestjsn(jso  jso) 
            {
               //do some here
                return View();
            }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: may i know what exactly the thing happen with in action i mean you are working with any third party api like facebook or twitter.